# Lua script on Redis Cluster

Tags: redis, lua, cluster-computing, redis-cluster

I have a Redis Cluster and I would like to execute a LUA script on a target node.
When I do that I receive an error from Redis Cluster that say that keys must be on the same SLOT, but the script executes two commands on only 1 key.

```
if redis.call('HEXISTS', 'TEST', KEYS[1]) == 1
    then 
        redis.call('HSET', 'TEST', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
        return 1
    end
return 0
```

I tried to use Hash Tag Key, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because you're trying to access a Redis key named `TEST`, but don't make it known to Redis or your Redis client by listing it in the EVAL command.

Redis Lua scripts take two argument lists, one is a general purpose (`ARGV[]`) and the other is a strict list of the keys the script is going to access (`KEYS[]`).

You may have swapped the key name and field names in the `HEXISTS` call, i.e. you may need to use:

```
if redis.call('HEXISTS', KEYS[1], 'TEST') == 1
    then 
        redis.call('HSET', KEYS[1], 'TEST', ARGV[1])
        return 1
    end
return 0
```

This should work as long as the key name is properly passed on to the `EVAL` command.

Comment: thanks! the solution was under my nose, but I don't see :)
The script below now works: 
if redis.call('HEXISTS', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) == 1
 then 
  redis.call('HSET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
  return 1
 end
return 0